# Finding an algorithm that finds the cheapest combination faster than O(2^N)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The problem definition is as follows: I need to find the cheapest combination of items that have parts that when combined, those parts can build at least one item. So if I need to build an item that has parts A, B, C, and D I need to find a combination of items (that I have to buy) that I can extract their parts from to make a new item.
[image: Visualization of the problem]

Basically in the image above the shape represents an item and the number represents the cost of that item. If I combine the triangle, star, and hexagon I can use their parts A, B, C, and D to make a new item. This is also the cheapest combination (from inspection). You can have leftover parts and the pricing of an item compared to how many parts and what type of parts they have, have no correlation. You can assume that each item will not have a part that you don't need (for example, no items will have a part 'E' - they can only have a part from the set {A, B, C, D})

**My solution** to the problem was using the power set algorithm to store each combination of items in an array. I then iterated over each combination to check if it was a valid solution. I used a hashmap<String, Boolean> and replaced a key,value pair in the hashmap with <partname, true> associated with the item I was iterating over and if my hashmap doesn't contain a false after iterating over the entire combination, that means that it is a valid solution.

I then added each valid solution to another set and I iterated over each index of the set and tracked the cost and this way, I was able to find the cheapest cost.

The only problem is that this algorithm is O(2^N) in space and time complexity. I'm wondering if I can do better and was looking for some advice on what data structures I should use. I was thinking of using a min heap and creating a new value in each part called weight  that was basically their cost divided by the amount of parts they had (the lower the value the better) and using that, I would implement a priority queue and I would just poll() to get the most valuable item. The problem that I encountered was in the situation that I could encounter conflicts: For example my current solution could be:
Square and then I try to add star but I find that my solution already has a part (square and star both share an A) should I remove the square and add the star or remove the star and look elsewhere in the min heap? It got pretty complicated with the amount of cases I was adding and I gave up on the priority queue idea, maybe it wasn't the right DS or I wasn't using it properly so I was looking for some advice if there is a perhaps better suited DS.

Comment: This is called the weighted set cover problem. You should be able to find lots of information about it by searching; here's a reasonable start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: Thanks so much! I didnt know if there was a specific name for this problem so this helps a lot.

Comment: It's going to be exponential in *some* parameter, but may be tractable if one of the parameters (like the maximum number of parts you might need?) is small.